# I want to display dynamic functioning buttons, based on the question list. Any suggestion would be great

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
export const QuizData = [
{
    id: 0,
    question: `What is the Capital of India?`,
    options: [`New Delhi`, `Mumbai`, `Pune`, `Hyderabad`],
    answer: `New Delhi`
},
{
    id: 1,
    question: `Any question here`,
    options: [`any`, `options`, `here`, ` `],
    answer: `ans`
},
{
    id: 2,
    question: `Any question here`,
    options: [`any`, `options`, `here`, ` `],
    answer: `ans`
},
]
//buttons
<button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={() => this.indexHandler(0)}
                  >
                    1
                  </button>
                  <br />
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={() => this.indexHandler(1)}
                  >
                    2
                  </button>
                  <br />
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={() => this.indexHandler(2)}
                  >
                    3
                  </button>
```

Above mentioned is the list of questions for reference. So, for now I am using static buttons,(for example as under //Buttons) and what I want is depending on the number of questions from data, the same number of buttons has to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good approach would be maintain two separate components-

1. Component which will list the questions (say `QuestionList.js`)
2. Question specific component to handle actions performed on that particular question. ( say `Question.js`)

> QuestionList.js

```
const QuestionList = () => {
    const QuizData = [...]
    const indexHandler = (id) => {...}
        
    return(
      <>
        {QuizData.map(question => (
             <Question key={question.id} id={question.id} indexHandlerCallback={indexHandler} />
           ))}
       </>)
    }
```

> Question.js

```
const Question = ({ id, indexHandlerCallback }) => {

  const hanldeClick = () => {
    // dispatch callback or any other actions
    
  }

  return (
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={hanldeClick}>
       {id+1}
    </button>
  )
}
```